# How scala HashMap inherit the "++" method while both superclasses TraversableLike and MapLike has same method name

Tags: scala, hashmap, scala-collections

When I was learning Scala source code of version 2.11.8, I found aspect of `HashMap` which confused me:

I noticed that there are 2 traits of `HashMap` for mixin directly or indirectly, which both defined `++` method:

- `TraversableLike`
- `MapLike`

It seems that these 2 traits both take `GenTraversableOnce` type as parameter, but with difference that `TraversableLike` trait defined one more parameter list for implicit `CanBuildFrom`, however in `HashMap.scala`, there is also defined an implicit `CanBuildFrom` in scope, but I have NO idea which `++` method HashMap will inherit from between these 2 traits, i.e. whether to use implicit `CanBuildFrom` or not. Please, see bellow my test example:

```
  //the paramter list for implicit ev is just evidence to limit the (A,B) as subtypes of (Int,String), to confirm with the expected return type.
  def addElements1[A,B](t: (A,B)*)(implicit ev: <:<[(A,B),(Int,String)]): HashMap[Int,String] = {
    val h = new HashMap[Int,String]
    h ++ t
    h
  }

  def addElements2[A,B](t: (A,B)*): HashMap[A,B] = {
    val h = new HashMap[A,B]
    h ++ t
    h
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    addElements1((1,"a"),(2,"b"),(3,"c"))
    addElements2((4,"d"),(5,"e"),(6,"f"))
  }
```

During debug process, I got different results of there 2 method, that is, the method `addElements1` inherits the method `++` from trait `TraversableLike`. Method `addElements2` inherits the method `++` from trait `MapLike`.

Is there obvious rule or condition for which method should me used for `HashMap`?

FYI: The inheritance chain of `HashMap` from these 2 traits are:

```
HashMap <- MapLike
HashMap <- Map <- Iterable <- Traversable <- TraversableLike
```

Thanks a lot for all your effort on this question in advance.